# Retrieve text from XML?

Tags: php, arrays, tags, preg-match

I want to get all words between XML tags from a array and the current outcome is:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in ........ on line 84

Result is: Array

```
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
    echo "sync is started <br>";
    $handle = fopen("XML/$file_name", "r");
    if ($handle)
    {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
        {
            $keywords=array("series_title","series_type","series_episodes");
            for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++)
            {       
                $pattern = "/<$keywords[$i]>(.*?)<\/keywords[$i]>/";
                preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);
                echo "result is: " . $matches . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_text = "error"; 
    }

    $upload_text ="finished";
    fclose($handle);
    //unlink('XML/' . $file_name);
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of your raw data, that you're trying to parse and is there any reason you're not using a XML parser instead?

Comment: You're trying to echo `$matches` which is an array. You need to loop through and print each found match that is in the array

Comment: $matches is an array, so you could do: `echo "result is: " . implode(", ", $matches) . "<br>";`  But really, look into using SimpleXML http://php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php

Comment: Yep, SimpleXML is the way to go!

Comment: thanks i will try this:) didnt know there was a parser or toolset to read xml.

Comment: example: 
-<anime>

<series_animedb_id>16201</series_animedb_id>


-<series_title>

<![CDATA[Aku no Hana]]>

</series_title>

<series_type>TV</series_type>

<series_episodes>13</series_episodes>

<my_id>0</my_id>

<my_watched_episodes>1</my_watched_episodes>

<my_start_date>0000-00-00</my_start_date>

<my_finish_date>0000-00-00</my_finish_date>

</anime>


 .            i want to extract all information between the anime tags, then read every tag for an anime_title. so whats between: <anime_title>THE TITLE</anime_title> and put it in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [**SimpleXML**](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php) to read the XML instead. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myanimelist>
    <anime>
        <series_animedb_id>1143</series_animedb_id>
        <series_title><![CDATA[.hack//Intermezzo]]></series_title>
        <series_type>Special</series_type>
        <series_episodes>1</series_episodes>
    </anime>
    <anime>
        <series_animedb_id>299</series_animedb_id>
        <series_title><![CDATA[.hack//Liminality]]></series_title>
        <series_type>OVA</series_type>
        <series_episodes>4</series_episodes>
    </anime>
</myanimelist>
XML;

$result = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach ($result->anime as $anime)
{
    echo trim($anime->series_title), "\n";
    echo $anime->series_type, "\n";
    echo $anime->series_episodes, "\n";
    echo "==========================\n\n";
}
```

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/202935)

In your case you would use `simplexml_load_file`, so your code would look like this:

```
<?php
$result = simplexml_load_file('your_file_path_here.xml');
foreach ($result->anime as $anime)
{
    echo trim($anime->series_title), "\n";
    echo $anime->series_type, "\n";
    echo $anime->series_episodes, "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks, i will try it tommorow and see if i can get it to work:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you can read in the [Official PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), the optional `preg_match` third argument will be an array

> matches
>
> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
> $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
> $matches[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will have the text that matched the first captured
> parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

So simply change your  :

```
echo "result is: " . $matches . "<br>";
```

to :

```
echo "result is: " . $matches[1] . "<br>";
```

Hope it helps

Comment: when i do that i get:
   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\import.php on line 83
   result is:

Comment: @ThaLioN mmm, there is a missing `$` sign in your regular expression pattern `$pattern = "/<$keywords[$i]>(.*?)<\/$keywords[$i]>/";`

Answer (score 0):

The value returned in the $matches parameter of the preg_match function is an array, the first element of which is the entire match, and the following elements are the capture groups (the parts between parentheses).

So, in your code, you'd only be interested in $matches[1]:

```
echo "result is: $matches[1]<br>";
```